# Rails 3: Adding data from one database to another identical one with different data avoiding id conflicts

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I've got two databases with the same schema, but with different data. What if I want to export one database data into the other? This could be done without much inconvenience if there were no id conflicts. However, not only there will be id conflicts between members of the same model (like there's a user with id 1 in the first database and a completely different user with the same id in the second database), but also trouble arises when you've got foreign key columns referring to ids which will have to change to avoid conflict.

I was wondering if there was any quick and clean way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have existing data in the target database?  If so, I imagine the source data needs to be appended to the target - but would not overwrite, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have existing data in the target database. It needs to be appended and shouldn't overwrite anything, but it needs to mantain the associations. There are no links between the data between the two databases, though, just associations, which must be preserved, between objects within the same database